# JSF URL Parameters get removed on Development, but work fine on production

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, glassfish

I have a Java EE 8 web application. the following page takes an id parameter to load appropriate data http://localhost:8080/qtube-v2/test.xhtml?id=25 . The page is backed by a CDI **@ViewScoped** .

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html lang="en"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      ...
      xmlns:p="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough">
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewAction action="#{testBean.redirectNoParameters}"></f:viewAction>
</f:metadata>
    <ui:composition template="index.xhtml">
```

when I click on:

```
<h:commandButton id="nextBtn" value="Next" action="#{testBean.nextQuestion}" >
    <f:ajax execute="@form" render="pass-section title-section"  />
</h:commandButton>
```

the url becomes http://localhost:8080/qtube-v2/test.xhtml and code breaks at one point.

the same project packaged for production on live website does not occur. the problem did not exists before and no change to code has been made. I want to add some fonctionality and I found the same code that worked perfectly before not working.

original application server : glassfish 5.0
I tried: glassfish 5.1 and Payara 5.194

What Can I do?

Comment: You tagged the question with glassfish. Are you saying it only fails on this and works in WildFly? That is what tags mean. And what you should do is investigate the differences between development and production (everything from client to server and in between)

Comment: no I have not tried WildFly. added glassfish just because it's the application server I'm using. I am still investigating.

Comment: That usually happens when `<f:ajax>` does not work at all. Please post a [mcve] and also post your findings wrt network traffic and javascript console (press F12 in your webbrowser). Try telling about the problem as if you're a developer of the web application, not as if you're the end user of the web application.

Comment: Any feedback? would be appreciated

Comment: @Kukeltje I'm still trying to create a minimal reproducible example . a lot of code to be removed/edited to isolate the problem. I would post an update if anything comes up.